# I keep getting undefined after async call in another function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I Have  2 functions one which uses async and await to grab data and place it into an array.
The second is acts like a checker to see if the user inputs a similar value as seen on the database

```
function repeatsChecker() {
  let api_data_values = []

  fetchData().then(data => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      api_data_values.push(data[i].name)
    }
  })

  return api_data_values

}

// testing for similarities

async function test() {
  let name = "Joe"
  let test = await repeatsChecker();
  console.log(test[0])
}

test()
```

When I compile a simple if statement everything returns true and when I do console.log(test[0])
it returns undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`repeatChecker` isn't returning a promise, so the fact that you're `await`ing doesn't have any meaningful effect. `console.log(test[0])` executes before `api_data_values.push(data[i].name)`.

Try this:

```
function repeatsChecker() {
  return fetchData().then(data => {
    return data.map(value => value.name);
  });
}
```

Or with async/await:

```
async function repeatsChecker() {
  const data = await fetchData();
  return data.map(value => value.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @NicholasTower im new to js can you help me understand which bit is the promise. as i believed the return api_data_values did it? or did it have to happen in the .then

Comment: `fetchData()` creates a promise. Your code then called `.then` on the promise, and calling `.then` on a promise creates another promise. However, since you didn't save the second promise to a variable or return it, that promise is lost. `return api_data_values ` returns an array, but that array is empty at the time you return it.